# How to put a word below an arrow?

Tags: typography

I would like to have an arrow with "1-1" above it and/or "onto" below it, with the arrow being normal size.  I get what I want with "1-1" using \stackrel:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\(

\stackrel{1-1}{\longrightarrow}\\

\stackrel{\stackrel{1-1}{\longrightarrow}}{onto}
\)

\end{document}
```

I would like to position "onto" similarly below the arrow.  But using a nested stackrel makes the arrow to small and too high.  What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `amsmath` provides extensible arrows with options for text above and below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  A \xrightarrow[\text{onto}]{\text{1--1}} B
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

PS: I am not sure, what `1-1` is supposed to mean. As mathematical expression it looks too trivial to me, thus I have interpreted it as text.

Comment: 1-1 is a common short name for being injective (there is a one to one relationship between the elements). Onto is short for surjective (hitting all elements in the target set).

Comment: @daleif Thanks. Then the dash seems to be the correct one.